# Initializing and Navigating a char**

Tags: c++, pointer-to-pointer

Okay, so consider this code:

```
char** pool = new char*[2];
pool[0] = new char[sizeof(char)*5];
```

As far as I know, this creates a pointer to an array of 2 char pointers. The second line then sets the first of these 2 char pointers to the first item in an array of 5 chars. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If I'm not wrong:

1. How would I go about initializing all of these chars?
2. How would I change a specific char? For example, setting the last char to NULL in each array.

Comment: for the "how" part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935752/how-to-memset-char-array-with-null-terminating-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know, this creates a pointer to an array of 2 char pointers. [...]
>
> ```
> char** pool = new char*[2];
> ```

No, that line creates a pointer to a pointer a character. The expression on the righthand side creates an array of 2 pointers to characters. You can initialize this a double pointer with an array of pointers, because the righthand side will decay into a double pointer.

> The second line then sets the first of these 2 char pointers to the first item in an array of 5 chars. [...]
>
> ```
> pool[0] = new char[sizeof(char)*5];
> ```

What do you mean by "the first of these two char pointers". You're only assigning to *one* pointer on that line.

> How would I go about initializing all of these chars?

By using a loop to iterate through the pointers and assigning valid memory to them.

> How would I change a specific char? For example, setting the last char to `NULL` in each array.
>
> ```
> for (char** p = pool; p != (pool + 2); ++p)
> {
>     *p = new char[/* amount of chars */];
>     (*p)[/* amount of chars */] = '\0';
> }
> ```

But this is a complete mess. It would be significantly more easy to use a vector of strings:

> ```
> std::vector<std::string> pool;
> ```

Comment: Thank you, looks like I had quite a few things wrong. Thanks for the clarification and simplification. I agree, it's a complete mess.