# C memset - elegantly add a null terminator

Tags: c, malloc, memset

I followed [How to memset char array with null terminating character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935752/how-to-memset-char-array-with-null-terminating-character) to add a null terminator when using the C `memset` api.

The code worked; I no longer got odd in-memory chars added to the end of my malloc'd char array, due to the null terminator.

```
/* memset does not add a null terminator */
static void yd_vanilla_stars(size_t *number_of_chars, char *chars_to_pad)
{
    memset(chars_to_pad, 0, *number_of_chars+1);
    memset(chars_to_pad,'*',*number_of_chars);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same?

Comment: If you are using `malloc()` to allocate for your array, why not use `calloc()` instead to get a zero-initialized allocation?

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Yep said the same thing - I guess OP doesn;t like it.

Comment: thanks @DavidBowling. Calloc is much tidier. I can remove this code.

Comment: Please do not edit solutions into the question. Instead you can post an answer in the Answer box, or accept a posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question suggests that `chars_to_pad` points to memory allocated using `malloc()`. Another alternative is to use [`calloc()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.2) instead. This function automatically zero-initializes the allocated memory, so there is no need to zero the allocation in a separate step.

An example might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t arr_sz = 11;
    char *arr = calloc(arr_sz, sizeof *arr);
    memset(arr, '*', arr_sz - 1);

    puts(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
**********
```

Answer (score 8):

You could simply do this:

```
memset(chars_to_pad, '*', *number_of_chars);
chars_to_pad[*number_of_chars] = '\0';
```

Also, why `number_of_chars` is a pointer?

Comment: I was trying to follow a pattern of Pass By Reference in my code. Would you pass by value for a size_t or int?

Comment: @rustyMagnet For such small types passing by value shouldn't be slower, and is definitely more readable. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/270435/2752075 (It discusses passing by value vs passing by const reference in C++; passing by pointer should work more or less like passing by reference)